# Safari box-sizing + inner border not working

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I'd like to add an inner border for a round image on hover, and I've this code:

```
.face {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.face:hover {
    border: 15px solid red;
}

.face:hover img {
    margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DSgk4/

It renders correct in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in Safari, why? As far as I know, safari supports box-sizing and border radius with the vendor prefixes. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the order of your vendor prefixes, place the CSS property `box-sizing: border-box;` last

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm seeing it OK in Safari 6 Mac. If possible I'd suggest using a background image, it would simplify your code.